# Selenium WebDriver very slow to load certain pages

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

In testing a website I'm finding certain pages on our test environment incredibly slow to load when using WebDriver (Consistently slow across The IE, Chrome and Firefox driver), however when visiting the same page in any other those browsers normally it loads in a much more timely way. Every indication seems to show the request for the page happening quickly, and the lag coming from downloading/rendering. Has anyone else encountered the same issue, and has a workaround/fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium doesn't seem to cache any data etc - or it clears the caches whenever it closes.  Is it possible that the pages that render slowly are downloading libraries, fonts or CSS files that are already cached in your normal browser instance?  Things like jquery and lightbox etc can soon add up.

Comment: No caching seems to account for some of it, but from send request to the DOMContentLoaded can take anything from 10-20 seconds. The delays I've been seeing can be upwards of a minute, can webdriver do anything interesting like limiting bandwidth?

Comment: On closer inspection we had a rouge JavaScript library being pulled down that was added a huge amount of latency

Comment: When i load webpages in my browser normally without selenium, time consumed is much less as compared to when i use selenium. Why is that?

Answer (score -2):

It might sound funny, but try restarting your computer. It helped in my case. And believe me, it wasn't first thing I tried out :D